# Script to Move Files in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, movefile

In Alfresco users can use rules to move files. How do I programmatically move a file from one folder to another?

Do you have an example?

I am using Alfresco 7.0 Share/Community version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Script :

```
var backupFolder = space.childByNamePath('testfolder');
if (backupFolder == null)
{
   backupFolder = space.createFolder('testfolder');
}

document.move(backupFolder );
```

Ref : https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-hub/javascript-api-cookbook/ba-p/293260

https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/6.1/develop/reference/repo-root-objects-ref/

Comment: Thank you. I saw this 2019 solution earlier and couldn't get it to work, so I reposted the question. Based on the example above, I tried to move the document to "testfolder". However, the file didn't move. Ideas? Kim

    var parentNode= document.parent;
    var movePath = parentNode.properties["cm:movePath"];
    var destination = sites/test/documentLibrary/testfolder(movePath);
    document.move(destination);

Comment: Check edited answer

Comment: Thank you Sanjay. The script works in my system.